# proxy private docker registry using nexus 3

Tags: nexus

is it possible to proxy a private docker registry that runs on docker distribution using nexus oss 3?

i am able to successfully proxy the docker hub, however when i try to proxy my own internal registry, i just end up with image not found errors.

```
2016-08-31 15:58:21,457+0000 WARN  [qtp331814152-140] admin org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V1Handlers - Error: GET /v1/repositories/company-npm/images: 404 - org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V1Exception$ImagesNotFound: images not found
2016-08-31 15:58:30,764+0000 WARN  [qtp331814152-140] admin org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Handlers - Error: GET /v2/library/company-java/manifests/latest: 404 - org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Exception: manifest unknown
2016-08-31 15:58:30,811+0000 WARN  [qtp331814152-51] admin org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V1Handlers - Error: GET /v1/repositories/company-java/images: 404 - org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V1Exception$ImagesNotFound: images not found
2016-08-31 15:58:46,379+0000 WARN  [qtp331814152-164] admin org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Handlers - Error: GET /v2/library/company-java/manifests/6.0.0: 404 - org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Exception: manifest unknown
```

the documentation for the feature does not seem to indicate if this is supported.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with Nexus 3.0.1-01.  For me the problem came down to namespacing.  Nexus inserts the /library namespace for all repository access commands when a namespace is left blank.  See https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/docker.html section 9.8.

So for example if I push an image to a hosted repository:

```
docker push my-registry.com:5000/myimage:latest
```

The proxy registry looks for the image as:

```
docker pull my-registry.com:5000/library/myimage:latest
```

Which of course doesn't exist.  (It would be really great if Nexus would add the /library namespace automatically on image push, or at least make this a configurable option at the repo level).

If you were to do the following:

```
docker push my-registry:5000/library/myimage:latest
```

or even:

```
docker push my-registry:5000/mynamespace/myimage:latest
```

The your proxy will be able to find the image.

```
docker pull my-proxy-registry:5000/mynamespace/myimage:latest
```

Comment: thanks for answering! 

i see that the docs say this 

`namespace
    the optional namespace of the specific image reflecting the owner, if left out this will silently default to /library and utilize Docker Hub`

but i'm still a little confused. since we are using docker distribution and not adding a namespace, shouldn't our images be found in `/library` already?

Comment: or is this perhaps an issue where b/c i'm not adding a namespace, nexus is automatically defaulting to docker hub which seems like it would be a bug in their implementation. someone from sonatype responded in their google group and i have contact w/ them in email, so if you have feedback, it may be good to weigh in there.

Comment: Looks like this is fixed in 3.0.2