# Proxying docker hub using Sonatype Nexus using registry-mirrors

Tags: docker, nexus, docker-registry

Similar to [Docker private registry with mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557384/docker-private-registry-with-mirror) but I am using Sonatype Nexus which is similar [nexus registry mirror docker hub not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58826325/nexus-registry-mirror-docker-hub-not-work) but I am also using a secure password protected repository

I have these settings in for the Docker daemon.

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [
    "https://repo.myprivate.com"
  ],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false
}
```

However, when I pull an image like `ubuntu` and look at the network access I see it is not hitting my server but the Docker Hub server.

I am guessing it is because I don't have my authentication set up for the mirror but I don't know the setting to use.

I also want to avoid doing [proxy private docker registry using nexus 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254652/proxy-private-docker-registry-using-nexus-3) which changes the names of the images to add the address.

To pull using the proxy I had to do `docker pull repo.myprivate.com/library/alpine` which I want to avoid.

It seems like it prioritizes the official repository first before going to the registry-mirrors.

Another thing I tried was to block off the IP addresses using Windows firewall, but it does not fall back to my private repo either.

Comment: Silly question: Did you restart the daemon after changing daemon.json?

Comment: yup.  I see it hitting it for some initial thing but for less than a second then starts downloading from Docker Hub.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the registry was HTTP (just a dev test) so I needed to add it to the insecure registries too:

```
{
  "insecure-registries": ["10.0.2.2:8181"],
  "registry-mirrors": ["http://10.0.2.2:8181"]
}
```

Comment: Thing is mine is a secure registry.  Still upvoting because it is valid.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled for quite a few hours with this same problem.

It was all about the Security->Realms. You need to select Docker Bearer Token Realm from the left column and move it to the right column.

Comment: Do this where? In Docker settings or Nexus settings.